# Comparing models with transformation from discrete to continuous

Tags: probability, cross-validation, kernel-smoothing

I have two models to fit a set of categorical features.

One uses an encoding followed by a Kernel Density Estimation (with cross-validated bandwidth search) to make a continuous distribution. I am aware that this might be a stupid idea, but bear with it.

One models the distribution directly using a probability table (with a floor on the probability of unseen combinations of features).

I would like to compare the accuracy of fit for these models using cross-validation. Is there any direct way to compare the likelihoods from the continuous probability density model with the likelihoods from the discrete probability model? If not, is there a logical prior I could use to allow this comparison to occur?

Comment: What does the response variable look like? Is it discrete?

Comment: The model will eventually be used for anomaly detection. So the response is the estimated likelihood of the [validation] data, which should be as high as possible because the data is not anomalous.